# LabVIEW Runtime does not save to Excel

Tags: excel, windows, save, runtime, labview

I had a working `LabVIEW` Program on my PC until my `LabVIEW` license timed out.
Before it expired, I created an executable file and a runtime support.
Everything just works out nicely as before, except the part, where I save my data into an `Excel` file. (Worked in the 'normal' developers version.)

On the bottom picture, the procedure of how I save the data is shown.
[image: Save Excel file]

I suggest there is a communication error between `LabVIEW` and `Excel`. Since I cannot develop my `LabVIEW` program any further (no license), it would be nice, if you have a fix on the `Excel` side.
Thanks a lot in advance!

**My Excel specifications:**
Microsoft Office Excel 2003 (11.8404.8405) SP3

**My Windows specifications:**
Microsoft Windows XP Professional
Version 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3 Build 2600
32bit

**My LabView specifications:**
LabVIEW Version 8.6

Comment: What version of  LabVIEW are you using?

Comment: @Dave_St I used LabView 8.6

Comment: Often things like hard coded filepaths can cause issues when creating executables or missing dependencies from the built application. NI now provide a free to use community version of LabVIEW which might be suitable if your project is within the scope of the community licence https://www.ni.com/en-gb/shop/labview/select-edition/labview-community-edition.html

Comment: What library or toolkit did you use to work with Excel? As @John says, the first thing to check is a path or dependency issue. I think it's unlikely you'll be able to fix this without editing the LabVIEW code and rebuilding the application.